# Two linear conections on a Riemannian manifold and one ... !!!

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $\nabla$ and ${\nabla}^*$ be two linear connections. If $f$ is a real valued function defined on $M$ and $X$ is a vector field,
 *my question is:* Does the value of $Xf$ change depending on the connection?
If yes, what is the deference?
If no, can I get the value of $X(g(Y,Z))$ for a linear connection using a Riemannian one?

Comment: do you are asking if $\nabla_X{\rm grad}f$ and $\nabla^*_X{\rm grad}f$ are equal?

Comment: No. $df$ does not change, and $Xf = df (X).$

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you. so the answer of the last question should be yes.

Comment: @janmarqz no I have a Riemannian connection and a non-metric connection and I want to evaluate $X(g(Y,Z))$ for the second one using the first one.

Comment: @janmarqz the LHS is a real function while the RHS is a vector field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some (intentional) ambiguity in the term "connection" and the symbol $\nabla$.

A "linear" connection $\nabla$ is defined to be a map $\nabla \colon \Gamma(TM) \times \Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(TM)$ which is $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear in the first slot and  satisfies a Lebniz-like rule
$$
\nabla_X (f Y) = \mathrm{d}f(X) Y + f \nabla_X Y
$$
where $\nabla_X Y$ is a shortcut for $\nabla(X,Y)$, and $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$. Thus, initially $\nabla$ is defined to act only on **vector fields**.

By insisting on the Leibniz rule we extend the action of $\nabla$ to all **tensor fields**, that is sections of finite tensor products of some copies of $T M$ and $T^* M$.

The Leibniz rule for this extended connection is stated as
$$
\nabla_X (T \otimes S) = (\nabla_X T) \otimes S + T \otimes \nabla_X S
$$
where $T,S$ are some tensor fields.

Comparing the two forms of the Leibniz rule we arrive to a **convention** that smooth functions can be treated as tensors of zero rank, and by definition $f \otimes T : = f T$.

To complete the picture we need to extend the action of $\nabla$ to smooth functions, and if we want the entire construction to be **natural**, the only possibility is to set $\nabla_X f := \mathrm{d}f(X)$.

In the nutshell, all connections agree on smooth functions.

---

To compute the value of $X(g(Y,Z))$ we just use the rules and the information available. Suppose, you have a linear connection $\nabla$ as above, and the Riemannian metric on $M$, so that you also have the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla^{LC}$. Recall that $\nabla^{LC} g = 0$, and $\nabla^{LC}$ is torsion free.

Let $S(X,Y)$ be the difference tensor of the two connections $\nabla$ and $\nabla^{LC}$, that is
$$
\nabla_X Y = \nabla^{LC}_X Y + S(X,Y)
$$

Now, 
$$
X(g(Y,Z)) = \nabla_X g (Y,Z) = \nabla g (X,Y,Z)
$$

To proceed, we need to understand how the connections differ on covariant tensors.

**Claim**. $\nabla_X \omega (Y) = \nabla^{LC}_{X} \omega (Y) - \omega(S(X,Y))$, where $\omega$ is a 1-form on $M$.

Using the multilinearity, we can find that 
$$
\nabla_X g (Y,Z) = \nabla^{LC}_X g (Y,Z) - g(S(X,Y),Z) - g(Y,S(X,Z))
$$
but $\nabla^{LC}_X g (Y,Z) = 0$, so finally
$$
\nabla_X g (Y,Z) = - g(S(X,Y),Z) - g(Y,S(X,Z))
$$

Comment: Thanks, a very appreciated work, again thank you